# Python. How to make it say something custom

Tags: python

Hey i don't know how to explain this so i will give an example.

```
print("hey eating # is a good idea")
```

What i want to happen is that when you type something. (`answer = raw_import`)
The # is what you typed.
Like if you typed orange. It would say (`"hey eating orange is a good idea`")
Also i want this to be after an else: statement.
I hope you understand my question.

This could be used for games, and other programs too. I bet many people have the same question and don't know what to google! Thanks!

Comment: Have you mis-typed `raw_input` as `raw_import`?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. http://www.python-course.eu/python3_formatted_output.php

```
fruit = "orange"
say = "hey eating {0} is a good idea".format(fruit)
print(say)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
say = "hey eating {} is a good idea"
if some_condition:
    # do something
else:
    a = raw_input("Enter your favourite fruit!")
    print s.format(a)
```